# WPF Databinding with ObservableCollection to Label

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ObservableCollection which I need to bind to 2 labels, first to show count of items in the collection and second to show the sum of values.

First label is bound to collections count property and second label is bound directly to ObservableCollection with a convertor to calculate total of all items

XAML looks something like this

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="itemList" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}"/>
    <Label Name="lblcount" Content="{Binding DataList.Count}" />
    <Label Name="lblTotal" Content="{Binding DataList, Converter={StaticResource calculateTotalConvertor}" />
</Grid>
```

My VM has a collection like this

```
    ObservableCollection<int> data = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    public ObservableCollection<int> DataList
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
```

My convertor code is

```
public class CalculateTotalConvertor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<int> collection = value as ObservableCollection<int>;

        return collection.Sum();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Issue is on adding new items in DataList, ListView and label showing count of items gets updated but "lblTotal" doesnt get updated with total count.

Basically how to force your binding to be evaluated on ObservableCollection changes ? How does it work directly for ListView or DataGrid but not for label ?

I know this problem can be solved by creating a property in VM to show total and raise property change when collection gets updated but is there is any better solution than that ?

Of-course this is simplified form of my actual problem, I dont have access to the ViewModel and the collection, its a third party control. I am creating a wrapper user control and have a relative binding with the view to its inner collection.

Comment: Did you try `set { data = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Data"); }` ?

Comment: Honestly, i would provide a property which does exactly what you want, and handle the logic in the VM. Using Converter for that is something weird and i try to avoid it as much as possible. Think about it, a convert should convert a value into another, you are converting a list to a number. A converter is called again if the initial value is updated, which it isn't in your case, it stays the same, just its inner state changes. Use your VM for that, providing and preprocess data  for the view is the main purpose of a view model.

Comment: @dowhilefor I agree to you...I wanted to know how does DataGrid updates on collection change and if I can do the same here. My actual usecase is lot different and complex. I have edited the question.

Comment: @AndreyGordeev RaisePropertychanged wont help as the collection property itself is not changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers correctly explain why it is not updating. To force it to update you can change your converter to an `IMultiValueConverter`:

```
public class CalculateTotalConvertor : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<int> collection = values.FirstOrDefault() as ObservableCollection<int>;

        return collection.Sum();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then change your binding to a `MultiBinding` which also pulls in the Count:

```
<Label Name="lblTotal">
    <Label.Content>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource calculateTotalConvertor}">
            <Binding Path="DataList"/>
            <Binding Path="DataList.Count"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Content>
</Label>
```

Now the second binding will notify that the binding needs to update when items are added or removed, but you can just ignore the count value and not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not updating because its bound to `DataList` and `DataList` has not changed, The count label updates because its bound to `DataList.Count` which is updated when an item is added to the list.

The only way I can think of to update the `Sum` label is to notify the UI that the `DataList` has changed, but this will cause the ListBox to rebind the list and it will performace will be a lot more expensive than just having a property on your model update the `Sum`.

So I think the best option would be to use a property on your model to caculate the sum using the `ObservableCollections` `CollectionChangedEvent` or in the logic that adds items to the list

Answer (score 0):

It works for `ListView` and `DataGrid`, because these are `ItemsControl`s that listen to the `ObservableCollection`'s `CollectionChangedEvent`, which is raised when the collection itself is changed by adding or removing items.

The `Label` on the other hand is a `ContentControl` that only listens to the `PropertyChangedEvent`. Since your DataList is the same `ObservableCollection` after the insertion as it was before, no events are raised.

**Just saw your edit:**

If you are creating a wrapping control, give the 3rd party control a name and hook up to its inner collection's `CollectionChangedEvent` from your control's code behind. That way you can still push update notifications to your wrapping view.

Go with the extra property, it will save you some code on the converter. From the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<int> _list = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    int _sum = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataList = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        DataList.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(DataList_CollectionChanged);
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void DataList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (object number in e.NewItems)
                    _sum += (int)number;
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (object number in e.OldItems)
                    _sum -= (int)number;
                break;
        }
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Sum");
    }

    public int Sum { get { return _sum; } }
    public ObservableCollection<int> DataList { get; set; }

    private void Add_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataList.Add(rnd.Next(0, 256));
    }

    private void Remove_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataList.Count == 0)
            return;

        DataList.RemoveAt(DataList.Count - 1);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```